# Orbifold chart.

Tags: differential-geometry, orbifolds

i'm trying to define an orbifold chart for the teardrop $R^2/Z_2$, where $Z_2$ acts via rotations. My advisor gave a tip: to use stereographic projections. But I'm  a little stuck. Any help?

Comment: Do you mean $S^2/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$? The case for $\mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is almost trivial. In fact, try that one first, and then somehow combine the charts for that one and stereographic projection to get charts for $S^2/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$.

Comment: hey, thanks I'll check this tip. But I think is the way my advisor thought.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wordy hint. The purpose of an orbifold is to capture the notion of "looks locally like a quotient." Towards this end, you can think of an orbifold chart as a map to the *quotient* of a manifold chart by a finite group action stabilizing 0 etc. (For ordinary manifold points in the orbifold, the finite group is trivial.)

Now do you see what to do?

Comment: thanks for the 'big picture'.